# Vectors subspace closure

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let W, U vector subspaces of V

and let $u,w \in V-{0}$ vectors such that

$u \in U \wedge u \notin W \wedge w \in W$

Can I say for a fact that $u + w \notin W$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a sum of a vector in $W$ and a vector outside of $W$ can't belong to $W$. If $u+w\in W$ then $u=(u+w)-w\in W$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

Suppose for the purpose of contradiction that $u + w \in W$. By the closure properties of a subspace, it must hold that
$$
(u + w) + (-1) \cdot w = u + w - w = u \in W,
$$
contradicting our premise.